# Android - Cancel all Notifications in a NotificationChannel

Tags: android-notifications

I'm surprised to find out this isn't already provided in [Google's API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#cancel(int)). The closest I was able to find was `cancel(String tag, Id int)`, but this requires an ID of a specific `Notification`. There is also `cancelAll()` but that cancels ALL notifications in every channel, which is not what I want. Is there an easy way to cancel all notifications, but only in a specific `NotificationChannel`? In other words, is there something akin to `cancellAll(String channelId)`?
We can assume API >= 26 (Oreo).